# CMake y pkg-config

Tags: c++, makefile

No tengo experiencia creando archivos `CMakeLists.txt` para compilar mi proyecto y estaba probando a hacer uno por primera vez.

Originalmente, desde la línea de comandos, compilaba el proyecto de la siguiente forma:

`g++ -Wall -std=c++11 src/main.cpp src/shootingStar.cpp $(pkg-config --libs --static allegro-static-5 allegro_image-static-5 allegro_primitives-static-5)`

El archivo `CMakeLists.txt`que he creado sin embargo, no acaba de funcionar.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(Test)

set(SRC_DIR "src")         # Source
set(INC_DIR "src/include") # Includes

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(ALLEGRO REQUIRED allegro-static-5 allegro_image-static-5 allegro_primitives-static-5)

include_directories(${INC_DIR})
include_directories(${ALLEGRO_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${ALLEGRO_CFLAGS}")

set(SOURCES

    ${SRC_DIR}/main.cpp
    ${SRC_DIR}/shootingStar.cpp

)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${ALLEGRO_LDFLAGS})
```

Al ejecutar el `makefile` generado por `cmake`, aparecen más de 200 referencias sin definir (Ej: `/.../allegro5/src/opengl/ogl_lock.c:550: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'`).

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de utilizar pkg-config en un archivo cmake ? (En caso de que ese sea el error).

Gracias.